# Updating a single row in TaffyDB

Tags: html, taffydb

I currently have a database setup within an html page and my requirement is to update a single row within the application.

I could refresh the database with "fresh" data, but that would require too much time.

I had a look at

```
 dbSports().update("aName", object.aname);
```

However it seems to update all the records in my database instead of just one. Are there any answers to this particular issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Documentation on the matter is missing a major chunk of information, but is covered in a presentation done by the author of the library (http://www.slideshare.net/typicaljoe/better-data-management-using-taffydb-1357773) [Slide 30]

The querying object needs to be pointing to the object you want to update and editing happening from there. i.e.

```
var obj = dbObject({
     Id : value.id
    }).update(function() {
        this.aName = object.aname;
        return this;
    });
```

Where the object in the query points to the ID of the row and the update function then points to it aswell and the callback updates the value that the application needs to update

Answer (score 0):

you first have to find the matching record, then update it

```
  yourDB({"ID":recordID}).update({
            "col1":val1,    
            "col2":val2,    
            "col3":val3
  });
```